# Async actions in Redux

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have a React App, I need to make an ajax call (in order to learn) to a online service (async) with Redux.

This is my store:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import duedates from './reducers/duedates'


export default applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore)(duedates);
```

This is the actions:

```
import rest from '../Utils/rest';

export function getDueDatesOptimistic(dueDates){
    console.log("FINISH FETCH");
    console.log(dueDates);
    return {
        type: 'getDueDate',
        dueDates
    }
}

export function waiting() {
    console.log("IN WAIT");
    return {
        type: 'waiting'
    }
}


function fetchDueDates() {
    console.log("IN FETCH");
    return rest({method: 'GET', path: '/api/dueDates'});
}

export function getDueDates(dispatch) {
    console.log("IN ACTION");
    return fetchDueDates().done(
        dueDates => dispatch(getDueDatesOptimistic(dueDates.entity._embedded.dueDates))
    )
}
```

And this is the reducer:

```
export default (state = {}, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'getDueDate':
        console.log("IN REDUCER")

        return state.dueDates = action.dueDates;
    default:
        return state
  }
}
```

I dont get what I'm doing wrong. The action is being called perfectly from the component. But then I get this error:

> Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

I guess I'm using wrong the react-thunk middleware.
What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Now the action is calling to the reducer, but the reducer, after changing state, is not re-running the render method

```
    case 'getDueDate':
        console.log("IN REDUCER")

        return state.dueDates = action.dueDates;
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think you should be using `compose` function, so it's like

```
import {
  createStore,
  applyMiddleware,
  compose
} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import duedates from './reducers/duedates'

export default compose(applyMiddleware(thunk))(createStore)(duedates);
```

Thunk allows an action creator to return a function instead of plain-object, so you use it like

```
export function getDueDates() {
  return dispatch => {
    console.log("IN ACTION");
    fetchDueDates().done(
      dueDates => dispatch(getDueDatesOptimistic(dueDates.entity._embedded.dueDates))
    )
  };
}
```

You were returning a Promise object, that was one part of the problem. Another part was that redux-thunk hasn't been properly applied. I bet `compose` should get the problem solved.

Comment: Great, seems to be working now. but in the reducer, when I `return` the state `return state.dueDates = action.dueDates;`, it is not calling render again.. Should I add something else?

Comment: Right now, in your code sample, both actions don't change state. You return state itself. Can you update your questions so I (or anybody else) could see the current situation?

Comment: updated, now I `return state.dueDates = action.dueDates;`

Comment: You shouldn't be doing that. This expression returns the value of the right part, which is not the way you want to reduce your state. Instead, try to use object spread: `return {...state, dueDates: action.dueDates}`.

Comment: Yes! that was it. Apparently, I must return a different state object, and not adding new data to the same

Comment: ugghh, sorry Redux, but this is *not* pretty at all....really "export default compose(applyMiddleware(thunk))(createStore)(duedates);" ?

Answer (score 17):

The accepted answer is either outdated, wrong or over-convoluted. Here are the docs on the compose subject:

http://redux.js.org/docs/api/compose.html

so we can do it like this instead:

```
import {createStore, combineReducers, compose, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const reducer = combineReducers({
    user: userReducer,
    items: itemsReducer
});


// here is our redux-store
const store = createStore(reducer,
    compose(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is possible to have a working solution without using the `compose` function too. Based on the documentation from the GitHub repo for [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)

*Solution works for `redux-thunk: ^2.0.0`*

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import duedates from './reducers/duedates'

export function configureStore(initialState = {}) {
  return createStore(
    duedates,
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey, Kevin, but where does `createReducer` come from?

Comment: HI @RishatMuhametshin, I have corrected the example above. `createReducer` was a function to avoid boilerplate code and taken from [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/reducers.js)

Comment: This worked for me. As stated by Kevin, compose was not required.

Comment: Awwwww!!!!! [scratching head] 

I ran into this issue because I missed the semicolon in the import of `import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'.`

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple answers with differing syntax. We'll I'm going to propose a solution without having to apply middlewares manually & without having to install `redux-thunk` separately.

The sole redux dependency:
`@reduxjs/toolkit: ^1.8.6`

> src/redux/store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import category from './features/category.feature';

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        category
    }
});

export default store;
```

> src/redux/features/category.feature.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { XHR_STATUS } from "../../misc/enums";
import axios from 'axios';
import { BASE_URL } from "../../misc/constants/xhr";

const initialState = {
    data: [],
    status: XHR_STATUS.NEUTRAL,
    errorMessage: ''
};

let slice = createSlice({
    name: 'category',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setStatus: (state, actions) => {
            state.status = actions.payload;
        },
        setData: (state, action) => {
            state.data = action.payload;
        }
    }
});

export const { setStatus, setData } = slice.actions;


export const fetchCategories = () => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(setStatus(XHR_STATUS.LOADING));
        const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}categories`);
        const { data } = response;
        dispatch(setData(data));
        dispatch(setStatus(XHR_STATUS.SUCCESS));
    }
}

export default slice.reducer;
```

> src/components/Categories/index.js

```
import { XHR_STATUS } from '../../misc/enums';
import { ListItem, List } from '@mui/material';
import CategoryBox from '../CategoryBox'; // This is my custom component to render a single Category
function Categories (props) {
    const { category } = props;
    switch(category.status) {
        case XHR_STATUS.NEUTRAL:
            return (
                'Waitng...'
            );
        case XHR_STATUS.LOADING:
            return (
                'Loading...'
            );
        case XHR_STATUS.SUCCESS:
            return (
                <List style={{ padding: '20px 0 20px 0', display: 'inline-flex', flexDirection: 'row', overflowX: 'scroll', width: '100%' }}>
                {category.data.map((c, i) => (  
                    <ListItem key={i}>
                        <CategoryBox category={c} />
                    </ListItem>
                ))}
                </List> 
            );
        case XHR_STATUS.ERROR:
            return (
                'Error...'
            );
    }
}
```